# How to filter twitter home timeline with Hashtag in Android application?

Tags: android, twitter, twitter4j, hashtag

Currently I make a twitter app for android.
I want to get user's home timeline only statuses which has specific hasttag.
But I can't find how to do that.
Only thing that I have is getting all home-timeline tweets and filtering that inside my app, 
but this is too overhead user's traffic.
Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this is offered. You can check the Twitter API for [GET statuses/home_timeline](http://dev.twitter.com/doc/get/statuses/home_timeline), which doesn't have any keyword query options.

Comment: Thank you. I wait a while someone give me solution even in unofficial way, but now I accept there is no way to do that. Thank you your answer.

Answer (score -1):

You can check this one [Filtered Twitter Feed](http://pipes.yahoo.com/techlifeweb/filteredtwitter). This will help you to filter Hash-tags related to particular user.